# PHP: Get specific content of a website

Tags: php, file, web

I want to get specific content of a website into an array.

I have approx 20 sites to fetch the content and output in other ways i like.
Only the port is always changing (not 27015, its than 27016 or so...)

[This is just one: **SOURCE-URL of Content**](http://www.gametracker.com/server_info/148.251.78.214:27015/)

For now, i use this code in PHP to fetch the Gameicon "cs.png", but the icon varies in length - so it isn't the best way, or? :-/

```
$srvip = '148.251.78.214';
$srvlist = array('27015');
foreach ($srvlist as $srvport) {
    $source = file_get_contents('http://www.gametracker.com/server_info/'.$srvip.':'.$srvport.'/');  
    $content = array(
                   "icon" => substr($source, strpos($source, 'game_icons64')+13, 6),
               );
    echo $content[icon];
}
```

Thanks for helping, some days are passed from my last PHP work :P

Comment: Is it only the image you are after? Can you not get it straight from the source? Not sure I get your point.

Comment: I want specific content of source-code, e.g. the image name, which varies in lenght, than playercount, playermax, servername, ... but i think if i get some help for only the imagename, i could get the rest for myself.

Comment: Is this game still played? It's now 15 years old.

Comment: Sure - it's simple oldschool :P

Comment: @StéphaneBruckert it's still got a lot of competitions being held and updates and patches coming up and a huge fan base ... yeah, still being played

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to look for the first `"` that comes after the `game_icons64` and read up to there.

```
$srvip = '148.251.78.214';
$srvlist = array('27015');
foreach ($srvlist as $srvport) {
    $source = file_get_contents('http://www.gametracker.com/server_info/'.$srvip.':'.$srvport.'/');  

    // find the position right after game_icons64/
    $first_occurance = strpos($source, 'game_icons64')+13;

    // find the first occurance of " after game_icons64, where the src ends for the img
    $second_occurance = strpos($source, '"', $first_occurance);

    $content = array(
                  // take a substring starting at the end of game_icons64/ and ending just before the src attribute ends
                   "icon" => substr($source, $first_occurance, $second_occurance-$first_occurance),
               );
    echo $content['icon'];
}
```

Also, you had an error because you used `[icon]` and not `['icon']`

---

Edit to match the second request involving multiple strings

```
$srvip = '148.251.78.214';
$srvlist = array('27015');

$content_strings = array( );

// the first 2 items are the string you are looking for in your first occurrence and how many chars to skip from that position
// the third is what should be the first char after the string you are looking for, so the first char that will not be copied
// the last item is how you want your array / program to register the string you are reading
$content_strings[] = array('game_icons64', 13, '"', 'icon');
// to add more items to your search, just copy paste the line above and change whatever you need from it

foreach ($srvlist as $srvport) {
    $source = file_get_contents('http://www.gametracker.com/server_info/'.$srvip.':'.$srvport.'/');  

    $content = array();

    foreach($content_strings as $k=>$v)
    {
        $first_occurance = strpos($source, $v[0])+$v[1];

        $second_occurance = strpos($source, $v[2], $first_occurance);

        $content[$v[3]] = substr($source, $first_occurance, $second_occurance-$first_occurance);
    }

    print_r($content);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to reduce the code or so? Because i have approx 10 content-strings i want to get, but than i have 20 vars with $first... and $second...

Comment: So, a way to reuse it for different strings ?

Comment: @am1 take a look at the second piece of code. You can add as many strings to look for as you want, and they all end up in an array.

Comment: Yeah, okay - but that looks really professional :) How to add now a second search-string?kay, but that looks really professional :) How to add now a second search-string?

Comment: @am1 ok, so let's say you also want to take the name / title of the server (working on your example). After the first `content_strings[] ...` just add the line `$content_strings[] = array('blocknewheadertitle', 21, '</span>', 'title');`. This will look for the first occurrence of blocknewheadertitle, skip until the start of the span text, and read until the end of that span. And it will save the info as title in your array

Comment: **THANKS*** so much! It works perfectly like i want, added some trim to remove spaces and catch the other content i want. Now i could put it into my slider - wow! Thanks! :)

Comment: No problem. Just remember to check the answer as approved if it's what you we're looking for

Comment: I did it!

Something other: Is there any way to get it faster? (Fetching)
For now it takes the source-code from approx 14 sites and this all takes approx 10 seconds, if my image-slider gets working. Something to improve it!??

Comment: Not really. That depends on your web host, on the servers you get your content from, not so much on the code itself. You can create a cron job that from time to time refreshes the info to a database, and you generate your site from the database, then it wouldn't matter how long it took to run this script. Or run the script from dynamically from ajax so that the page loads and when it gets the new info it also loads that to your page. But as is, there's no really faster way.